# Add tooltips for ng-tagsinput

Tags: tooltip, ng-tags-input

I have been using ng-tagsinput from benford -> http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

I am trying to add tooltips for tags added in input field. This tooltip should show contents of the tag. Can anyone help me to add tooltips for the tag?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I have made little changes in latest file of ***ng-tags-input.js*** and ***ng-tags-input.min.js*** that will solve your requirement of tool tip.

I have added `ng-attr-title={{$getDisplayText()}}` at **ngTagsInput/tag-item.html** template section in js file. by simply adding title attribute to the span tag will work. This change made for you, but @mbenford  the creator of this library may add this as an feature.
You can download the file from below links. and you can see the tooltip on tags :)

https://ufile.io/k5v8w - min js

https://ufile.io/sntbh - unminified js

Comment: Hi @Mohammed Gadi, Thanks for changes. It looks good to show simple tooltips. It is also static text. I would like to have dynamic text in tooltip. Example - To show content of selectedTag on Hover. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but a template approach is better. Just use the "template" attribute and add tooltip to your template. Details here: 
http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/guides/custom-templates

Comment: Hi @user4848830 This help for a start, but when I try to call a function to retrieve the dynamic tooltip, it cant recognize the controller, and hence cant call the function. Any ideas on that?